# How to write the mysql query for return 4 rows exactly

Tags: mysql

I want to display the 4 rows from the table. I have using following query

> SELECT field_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4;

The table contains more than 4 values means it display the first 4 rows perfectly. But it less than 4 rows means I need the result for following result

1. It display 2 rows only means

> field_name 
>   row1 
>   row2 
>   row2 
>   row1

2. It display 3 rows only means

> field_name 
>   row1 
>   row2 
>   row3 
>   row1

How can i get this result?

Comment: Your explanation is very unclear, could you please refine it so we could help ?

Comment: where is the problem , please more details or clear what you want exactly

Comment: If I got you right than [SQL-FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ecf7) says everyting is ok ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
Select * from (

select * from tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4
union all 
select * from tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4
union all
select * from tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4
union all
select * from tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4) as table1   LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very nice solution, but it should work: you can repeat your query 4 times using UNION ALL and limit to 4 results:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT field_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT field_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT field_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT field_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name = 'value' LIMIT 4;
) a LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column_Name
FROM (
SELECT Column_Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column_Name) AS RowNum
FROM [dbo].[AttendanceLog]
) AS MyDerivedTable
 WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 1 and 4
```